# read Many to many relation field during save

Tags: python, django

i'm trying to make some operations during model save with many-to-many relation field of the same model

```
class Article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="New article")
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post_to = models.ManyToManyField(Account) 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        print self.post_to.all()
```

instead of

```
print self.post_to.all()
```

could be some function to work with self.post_to.all() query set

the problem is that when i create **new** article and press SAVE button the query set is empty

```
<QuerySet []>
```

after that i enter into this article and press SAVE again the query set is not empty

```
<QuerySet [<Account: Template>]>
```

I think that problem in time when object is saved
but i can't get how to read this field during creation.

Comment: Are you using model forms?

Comment: what do u mean? i use models . i want to make some operation with objects from query set during save, but it is empty...

Comment: If you mean Account model - it is also just a model class     Account(models.Model): with field name CharField